# How do you remove selected rows from a JTable?

Tags: jtable

I've tried this:

```
public void removeSelectedFromTable(JTable from)
{
    int[] rows = from.getSelectedRows();
    TableModel tm= from.getModel();

    while(rows.length>0)
    {
        ((DefaultTableModel)tm).removeRow(from.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[0]));

        rows = from.getSelectedRows();
    }
    from.clearSelection();
}
```

But, it sometimes leaves one still there. What can be the problem?

Comment: This didn't worked for me

Answer (score 25):

It doesn't work, this is better:

```
public void removeSelectedRows(JTable table){
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
   int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
   for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
     model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
   }
}
```

Comment: So you subtract i to account for index difference from the rows which have already been removed, but that assumes the rows which have been removed already are above the row that's "about to be" removed.  Is that always a safe assumption?

Comment: it's not. 'for' should go other way, with "i--"

Comment: This does not account for table sorting.

Comment: -1 Doesn't work with sort. You should use table.convertRowIndexToModel(index);

Answer (score 11):

```
int[] selectedRows = getTable().getSelectedRows();
        if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
            for (int i = selectedRows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tableModel.removeRow(selectedRows[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
int numRows = table.getSelectedRows().length;
for(int i=0; i<numRows ; i++ ) {

    m_tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
}
```

Comment: Voted up as this **works perfectly**! Because _getSelectedRow()_ returns the index of the first selected row...

Answer (score 5):

**Java 8+ streaming solution:**

*JTable table;

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();*

```
IntStream.of(table.getSelectedRows())
            .boxed()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
            .map(table::convertRowIndexToModel) // support for sorted table
            .forEach(model::removeRow);
```

Comment: I really liked this solution but it didn't account for sorted tables.. I've edited the answer to also give this solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
removeRows: {
    int[] lines = t.getSelectedRows();
    if(lines.length==0)
        break removeRows;
    for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i]=t.convertRowIndexToModel(lines[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(lines);
    for(int i=lines.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        dtm.removeRow(lines[i]);    
    }
}
```

Working with sorting, moving columns, multiple selection, etc.

Comment: The trick is to sort the rows to remove and work from bottom up!

Answer (score 2):

try this is perfect work and simple

```
DefaultTableModel df1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int rs[] = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = rs.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {

        int k = rs[i];

        df1.removeRow(k);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this,

```
public void removeSelectedFromTable(JTable from)
{
        int[] rows = from.getSelectedRows();
        TableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) from.getModel();


        for (int row : rows) {
            tm.removeRow(from.convertRowIndexToModel(row));
        }

        from.clearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me!

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();
    int nbrrow=Table.getRowCount();

        if(nbrrow>=1){
            int[] rows = Table.getSelectedRows();
            if(rows.length>=1){
            if(Table.getModel().isCellEditable(Table.getSelectedRow(),Table.getSelectedColumn())
                       &&Table.isEditing()==true)
               {
                   Table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                    for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){ 
                     model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
                   }
               }else{
                            for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){ 
                             model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
                           }

                }
            for(int i=0;i<Table.getRowCount();i++){
                           model.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
                       }
              Table.revalidate();
              Table.repaint();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
List<Object> selectedObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int row : selectedRows) {
    selectedObjects.add(tableModel.getObject(row));
}
for (Object obj : selectedObjects) {
    tableModel.removeObject(obj);
}
```

// My TableModel is a subclass of this:

```
public abstract class ListTableModel<T> extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<T> data;

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getObject(int row) {
        return data.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: DefaultTableModel doesn't have method "getObject" :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public void removeSelectedFromTable(JTable table) {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int indexes[] = table.getSelectedRows(); 
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            res += (i>0)?(indexes[i]-indexes[i-1]-1):0;
            int index = table.convertRowIndexToModel(indexes[0]+res)
            model.removeRow(index);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int selectedIndex = table_.getSelectedRow();
while (selectedIndex >= 0) {
    int modelIndex = table_.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedIndex);
    tableModel_.removeRow(modelIndex);

    selectedIndex = table_.getSelectedRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is woked for me.enter code here

```
public void removeSelectedFromTable(JTable from)
    {
        int[] rows = from.getSelectedRows();
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) from.getModel();
        for (int i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            tm.removeRow(rows[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work:

```
do {
    ((DefaultTableModel) jXTable1.getModel()).removeRow(jXTable1.getSelectedRows()[0]);
} while (jXTable1.getSelectedRowCount() > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
if(tablaNotif.getSelectedRows().length>0){
    int[] rows = tablaNotif.getSelectedRows();
    if(tablaNotif.getSelectedRows().length<2) {
        modelo.remove(tablaNotif.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[0]));
    } else{
        for(int i = 0; i<tablaNotif.getSelectedRows().length;i++) {
            modelo.remove(tablaNotif.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[i]));
        }
        modelo.remove(tablaNotif.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[(tablaNotif.getSelectedRows().length-1)]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stream solution above doesn't take into account sorting, it may be fixed this way:

```
        IntStream.of(table.getSelectedRows())
            .boxed().map(i -> table.convertRowIndexToModel(i))
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel())::removeRow);
```

Answer (score -2):

I looked at all the solutions, but there are some exceptions, so I would like to add this answer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < raws.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("I : " + i);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {
        defaultTableModel.removeRow(0);
        jTStockJournal.clearSelection();
        defaultTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for firing events on behalf of the model (it's the model's own job)

Answer (score -2):

That solution works with header sorting and updates automatically the table (i.e.: it is not required to rebuid it).

The "Collecions.sort in reverse order" ennables to avoid IndexOutOfBondException.

```
private void deleteSelectedRows() {
        int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
        table.clearSelection();

        // get model rows
        List<Integer> selectedModelRows = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i =`enter code here` 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            selectedModelRows.add(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]));
        }

        Collections.sort(selectedModelRows, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int selectedModelRow : selectedModelRows) {
            tableModel.removeRow(selectedModelRow);
            tableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(selectedModelRow, selectedModelRow);
        }
}
```

Comment: -1 for firing events on behalf of the model (it's the model's own job)

Answer (score -2):

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        Vector newRow = new Vector();
        defaultModel.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
        i = i - 1;
    }