# Receiving a lot of error messages when trying to delete rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with deleting rows from JTable. My code based on this question: [How do you remove selected rows from a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655325/how-do-you-remove-selected-rows-from-a-jtable)

```
public static void removeSelectedRows(JTable table){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(rows[i]);
    }
}
```

When I press button to delete selected rows:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Delete selected");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        removeSelectedRows(table);
    }
});
```

I receive a lot of error messages in my terminal:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
at ConfFrame.removeSelectedRows(ConfFrame.java:37)
at ConfFrame$1.actionPerformed(ConfFrame.java:63)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3315)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You're assuming that getModel() returns a DefaultTableModel, and it doesn't, as the exception shows. Don't make that assumption, because it's incorrect, as you see. If you want the table to have a DefaultTableModel as its model, then create one and call setModel().

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Another error you are making, which isn't obvious maybe: `table.getSelectedRows();` returns **view** indices. You are using those **view** indices to remove rows from the **model**! You should convert those view indices to model indices using `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel` first to convert to model indices and use those to remove from the model. You will know why that is important when you start sorting rows in the JTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your table with fixed data so an inner class is used as your `TableModel`.

Instead you need to create your `JTable` with code something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Now in your code you will be able to get the TableModel and cast it to a DefaultTableModel.